# Azure push-notification hub don't work after failure

Tags: azure, apple-push-notifications

On the server side, we are using Azure with SDK Azure Tools Version: 2.2

We send push-notifications on iOS with a failure (APNS Errors did appear in Dashboard). After this failure, push-notifications don't work on this tag and hub all the time. 
How can we fix this situation without clearing all registrations and creating a new tag?

Usually scenario looks like this:
1. Tag works fine.
2. We register some device with wrong certificate for example. Errors in dashboard.
3. Tag doesn't work totally. Errors in dashboard. Devices which previously got notifications doesn't get it now.

Can we change something to make old(added before step 2) devices able to get notifications?

Comment: Hi, couple of questions. First time you send to some tag, hub accepts that message but notification is never delivered and APNS error appears in the dashboard, is this right? Second time you send to the same tag, what does exactly happen then (request fails, notification is just not delivered again)?

Comment: @efimovandr thx for your comment! Added some data to description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notification Hub is very sensitive to APNS certificates/tokens. There are couple rules:

1. Avoid to use invalid (fake) device tokens or clean them up before send to real devices. If it is required to run some unit tests with fake tokens then it is better to create separate hub for such purpose.
2. When it is time to switch from the sandbox APNS certificate/endpoint to the production one (or back) it is required to clean up ALL existing APNS registrations. Or even better way - just create separate hubs for test and for production.